# Error al instalar gema "mongo"

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rubygems

Tengo un problema al instalar la gema de mongodb, ¿alguien puede decirme el problema?

```
$ gem install mongo -v 2.2.4
ERROR:  Error installing mongo:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bson-4.3.0/ext/bson
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180307-14304-1wbpuht.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bson-4.3.0/ext/bson
make "DESTDIR=" clean
"make" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bson-4.3.0/ext/bson
make "DESTDIR="
"make" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bson-4.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/bson-4.3.0/gem_make.out
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
```

Ya intenté instalando las gemas bson y bson-ext pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Answer (score 3):

Por el error que devuelve, te falta instalar la herramienta make.

Veo que trabajas con windows: 
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Un saludo.